# Selenium finding a select dropdown

Tags: java, html, selenium, drop-down-menu, webdriver

I am working on a test but I cant see to be able to find a drop-down menu on the page.  I have been able to identify most of the the other elements on the page.  For one button I had to implement a JavaScript workaround which I don't really understand so it could be a similar issue to to that.  I'm not sure how to implement that in this case(drop-down) as that was for a button.

Anyhow, the drop-down uses the Select tag.

```
<div id="z_bc" class="dco">
<div class="dco_c">
<table class="d_FG" role="presentation">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr id="z_bd">
<td class="fct_w" colspan="2">
<div class="d2l-select-container">
<select id="z_be" class="vui-input d2l-select" name="z_be">
<option value="1" selected="selected">All conditions must be met</option>
<option value="2">Any condition must be met</option>
</select>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Th want to select the second option: "Any condition must be met"

My code is as follows:

```
//test begins
npc.setHeadline(headline);
npc.setContent(content);
npc.click_create_and_attach();
Thread.sleep(1000);
ManageWindowFocus mwf = new ManageWindowFocus();
mwf.switch_to_pop_up_window(driver);

//driver.manage().window().fullscreen();
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'd2l_cntl_')]")));


Select conditiontype = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("z_b")));
Thread.sleep(1000);
conditiontype.selectByIndex(6);
Select role = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("z_g")));
//select role = Student
Thread.sleep(1000);
role.selectByIndex(14);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create")).click();
mwf.revert_to_parent_window(driver);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
Thread.sleep(1000);

WebElement access = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='z_be']"));
Select dropdown = new Select(access);
Thread.sleep(1000);
dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
```

The method revert_to_parent_windows is as follows:

```
public void revert_to_parent_window(WebDriver driver){
    ///this method returns the handle of a second window that pops up

    Set<String> AllWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    String window1 = (String) AllWindowHandles.toArray()[0];
    String window2 = (String) AllWindowHandles.toArray()[1];

    driver.switchTo().window(window1);



}
```

I get the error when I try to identify the drowpdown list:

```
WebElement access = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='z_be']"));
```

Error: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@id='z_be']"}

I've also tried by cssSelector:

```
WebElement access = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id=z_be]"));
```

and scrolling down the page to make the dropdown visible on the page but to no avail.

Not sure if it is a problem with reverting back to the original window or if there is an issue trying to locate the drop-down itself.

***EDIT***

**I managed to get this working now by using the absolute xpath:**

```
 WebElement access = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[7]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/form/div/table[5]/"
        + "tbody/tr[3]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/select"));
```

But when I tried using the xpath it actually seems to work but with a different error:

```
 WebElement access = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='z_be']"));
 Select dropdown = new Select(access);
```

with error: UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "div" on the second line

**If anyone has a better solution or can teach me an alternative method that gets around this error it would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: no efforts needed for us to solve it anymore? :) then congrats ! :) But ofcourse to add a comment, using xpath with location like indexing is not  a good idea if you want it to work dynamically :) I'll rather use driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='z_be']")) since it is the ID rather than what you did :) but anyway, if you just want to find it then select, you won't have a problem anyway for a static programming :)

Comment: @jace Hi Jace the issue was that driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='z_be']")) was not working it couldnt locate the dropdown for some reason any other ideas to solve it?

Comment: how did you know that was not located by xpath then? :)

Comment: @jace yeah your probably right.  I rechecked everything I tried the following: WebElement access = driver.findElement(By.id("z_be")); and it seems to be ok but i get the error Element should have been "select" but was "div" on the next line

Comment: @jace Hi jace sorry to bother you but any ideas on how to solve the above issue:  Element should have been "select" but was "div"?

Comment: hi @tarquin, can you use chat? so that only important comments will be commented here :) I just want to ask some question :)

Comment: i just want to ask what do you mean in here :) it is quite not clear "Element should have been "select" but was "div""

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128665/discussion-between-tarquin-and-jace).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the Select option working but I found a workaround by doing the following:

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("option[value='2']")).click();